# list of variations with repetitions for 4 elements

Tags: excel

for gaming purpose, I want to get a list of all possible combinations made from 4 predefined elements (letters or words). I'd like to be able to create such list myself in Excel. But without macros if possible.
e.g.

```
aaaa
aaab
(...)
cddd
dddd
```

listed in separate cells

Comment: That's very nice. Did you just want to notify us of your plans or you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your four elements are in A1:A4, enter this **array formula**** in your first cell of choice:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(INDEX(INDEX($A$1:$A$4&TRANSPOSE($A$1:$A$4),N(IF(1,1+INT((ROW(INDIRECT("1:16"))-1)/4))),N(IF(1,1+MOD((ROW(INDIRECT("1:16"))-1),4))))&TRANSPOSE($A$1:$A$4),N(IF(1,1+INT((ROW(INDIRECT("1:64"))-1)/4))),N(IF(1,1+MOD((ROW(INDIRECT("1:64"))-1),4))))&TRANSPOSE($A$1:$A$4),N(IF(1,1+INT((ROW(INDIRECT("1:256"))-1)/4))),N(IF(1,1+MOD((ROW(INDIRECT("1:256"))-1),4)))),ROWS($1:1))
```

Copy down a further 255 rows.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*